# Задача по PHP, работа с рандом

Tags: php

Это последний вопрос ребят)) :D. есть у нас черепаха, возможность что черепаха сделает 3 шагов 50% возможность что сделает -6 шагов 20%, и что +1 шаг возможность 30%, короче, обкуренная черепаха. как сделать эти возможности на php? С рандомом только, как вариант думал так но это не то, сами можете понять почему)

```php
$x = rand(0, 50);


if($x<=50){
    echo("+3 ");
}
if($x<=20){
    echo(" -6 ");
}
if($x<=30){
    echo(" +1 ");
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/f41f8688a2b3b8f7b6df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//100%
$x = rand(1, 100);

if ($x <= 50) { //50%
    echo("+3");
} else if ($x <= 70) { //20%, т.к. 70-50=20
    echo("-6");
} else { //оставшиеся 30%
    echo("+1");
}
```

Comment: Зачем проверять условие `1 <= $x`?

Comment: Только ради наглядности...

Comment: Тогда в конце добавьте `if ($x <= 100)`. Это не наглядность. Это наоборот сбивает с толку

Comment: ваш код даст одинавое распределение при любых весах. рандом вам выкидывает любые числа с одинаковой вероятностью.

Comment: @Kirill, подождите. Если рандом возвращает любые числа с одинаковой вероятностью, то чем больше диапазон чисел, тем больше в него равновероятных чисел попадёт. Неужели в отрезки [1; 2] и [3; 100] попадёт одинаковое количество чисел?

Comment: посмотрите на примере: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca22872a3446ea66896a69578b39885f9bdbd592
Подставьте в исходный массив любые веса, распределение в масиве $ch2 всегда будет в рамках выходных того герератора который использует rand() (правда я не знаю какого именно, надо будет почитать :))

Comment: Хотя, я наверное ошибся ))

Comment: Да, пардон, плюсану обратно

Comment: @Kirill, `errare humanum est` :D